# Why does some programs block the Main Thread of Windows OS and the GUI

Tags: multithreading, user-interface, operating-system, block

What is the main reason for programs to block the main thread on Windows Os, like Visual Studio does when loading the project, it blocks the whole Operating System GUI and you have to wait for it to finish the loading of the project. Have they done bad programming on Visual Studio or is it unavoidable blocking the OS GUI if so why is that.

Regards

Comment: Well, I would call it 'economical programming':)  To start with, many GUI systems suffer from legacy design, left over from prehistory when processors had one core.  Another factor is that visual components common in IDE, eg treeviews, are CPU intensive to render with the one GUI thread.  I would not be surprised if many IDE implementations are a bit umm..'stale' and could do with a multithreaded refresh:)

Comment: Thanks nice answer.